# Is it possible to modify Salesforce email template type

Tags: email-template

My question is regarding the possibility of modification of email template type(Text, HTML, Custom, Visualforce) after an email template has been created.

Basically, I have an existing text template that I wish to convert to VF template.

I have checked the possibility of doing this using the UI and found that it is not.

Additionally, I have even tried modifying the template's metadata and uploading via ant. Ant task succeeds but no changes occur in the email template.

Actually I want to use <apex:repeat> for child objects in the email template, which sadly is not supported in text template.

I can't delete the template because it has already been released in a managed package. The only way out I see is creating another template and using it where ever the current template is being used.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be forced to create a new template. There's no way to alter a template's type once created.